# Rails distinct validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How to distinct which validator failed ?

I have multiple validations on the same field:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1, maximum: 20 }
     validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

When I save the user as user.save - I want to distinct what failed.

```
if user.__not_valid_name_length__?
    # name length wrong
    # do smth 1
end
if **user.__not_valid_name_unique__?
    # name is not unique
    # do smth 2
end
```

I can access user.errors[:name] and see all error messages for the field.
But I don't want to rely on message text which can change.

Is there any way to know which validator failed?

Answer (score 0):

A feature to return machine-parseable symbols instead of strings was committed to Rails almost a year ago, but it's still not available in the `4-x-stable` branch. You can use it if you use the edge version, and it will be available in Rails 5.

Example:

```
user = User.new
user.valid?
user.errors.details[:name] # returns: [{error: :blank}, {error: :too_short}]
```

More info:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18322

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb

Comment: do you know if this is available in 4.2.5? Or definitely only in version 5?

Comment: I believe it will not be available until Rails 5, at least for now that isn't merged into the `rails-4-2-stable` branch.

Comment: in the meantime you can use it if you include it as a gem: https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in callbacks for rails validation fails, for rails validation available callbacks are:

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`

To learn more about callback, please read this [call_back](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Checking validation fail base on the message is no good approach. It may change in different scenarios i.e internationalization. Do it  by defining the `method for validation` i.e

```
# check presence_of validation

def is_name_present?
  self.name.present?
end

# check uniqueness validation

def is_name_uniqe?
  User.where(name: self.name).count == 0
end
```

Use one which suit you best, I suggest use `after_validation`

```
after_validation :post_validatiom

def post_validation
  unless is_name_present?
    # do_someting
  end

  unless is_name_uniqe?
    # do_something
  end
end
```